# How to append data only once using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Below is the my code for clicking functionality of tabs.

```
<body>
    <div class="row-fluid">
        <div class="span1 offset1">
            <div class="tabbable" align="center">
                <ul class="nav nav-tabs nav-stacked">
                    <li class="active"><a href="#tabs-1" data-toggle="tab">Eat</a>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#tabs-2">Drink</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="1"></div>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $("a[href=#tabs-1]").click(function() {

            for (i = 0; i < mytabs.length; i++) {
                $('div').append("<br>" + mytabs[i] + "<br>");
            }
        });
    </script>
</body>
```

And here I am using javascript to store the values of tabs in array

```
<script>
    $(function() {
        $("#tabbable").tabs();
    });

    var i;
    var mytabs = new Array();
    mytabs[0] = "Saab";
    mytabs[1] = "Volvo";
    mytabs[2] = "BMW";
</script>
```

Now I want that after clicking on tabs the values stored in data should get displayed. But what my code is doing , It is showing the data as many times as the data is stored in array. Means I want output as Saab,Volvo,BMW but is displaying it three times. Can anyone help me in this that what to use instead of append so that i get the desired output.

Comment: As far as  I can see, the data is only appended once. Of course it will be appended again whenever you click on the first tab, is that what you mean?

Comment: @Felix Kling:No Means I want output as Saab Volvo BMW But it is displaying as Saab Volvo BMW three times on first click itself So, I wanted to know, is there another method instead of append to get the desired output.

Comment: When clicking on your link you will add all `mytabs` fields to *all existing* `div`s (`$('div')`)! This is probably not what you want. As dann said: use `$('div#1')` instead.

Comment: @cars10: Didn't notice that, good catch!

Comment: use `$('div#1').append("<br>"+mytabs[i]+"<br>");`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Try using `jQuery.one` http://jsfiddle.net/adiioo7/UFBzn/1/

**JavaScript:-**

```
 var i;
 var mytabs = new Array();
 mytabs[0] = "Saab";
 mytabs[1] = "Volvo";
 mytabs[2] = "BMW";

 $(function () {
     $(".tabbable").tabs();

     $("a[href^=#tabs-]").one("click", function () {
         for (i = 0; i < mytabs.length; i++) {
             $($(this).attr("href")).append("<br>" + mytabs[i] + "<br>");
         }
     });
 });
```

**HTML:-**

```
<div class="row-fluid">
    <div class="span1 offset1">
        <div class="tabbable" align="center">
            <ul class="nav nav-tabs nav-stacked">
                <li class="active"><a href="#tabs-1" data-toggle="tab">Eat</a>

                </li>
                <li><a href="#tabs-2">Drink</a>

                </li>
            </ul>
            <div id="tabs-1"></div>
            <div id="tabs-2"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: If i want to generalize it for all the tabs how would i do i t

Answer (score 2):

Quick and dirty, but does the job

```
$('div#1').empty();

for (i=0;i<mytabs.length;i++)
    $('div#1').append('<br/>' + mytabs[i] + '<br/>');
```

It will clear the div before adding content. Is this what you're asking for?

Comment: also, using `$('div')` will append to all div. use `$('div#1')`

Comment: @dann Yeah, was about to change it. Thanks

Comment: @Johan, Dann:Thanx a lot it served my purpose.

Answer (score 2):

This works  for me:
    $('div#1').empty();
    $('div#1').append('your code here');

Answer (score 1):

Try this

Your html has 3 div elements . First of all make sure where you want (in which Div) you want to append the tabs.Below code will append tabs in div with id="1" .Other wise it will append in all the div s.

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
$("a[href=#tabs-1]").click(function()
            {
        $('div#1').empty();
          for (i=0;i<mytabs.length;i++)
            {
              $('div#1').append("<br>"+mytabs[i]+"<br>");
        }
        });
 </script>
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
$('div').html("<br>"+mytabs[i]+"<br>");
```